# PHP: When I press the "send" button it should print the name and surname I entered in the form

Tags: php, html, forms, cookies

When I press the "send" button it should print the name and surname I entered in the form, how can I solve?

```
<?php
//Form generato dinamicamente dalla pagina php
echo "<FORM NAME='modulo' METHOD='post' ACTION=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].">
Nome:<INPUT TYPE='text' NAME='nome'><BR><BR>
Cognome:<INPUT TYPE='text' NAME='cognome'><BR><BR>
<INPUT TYPE='reset' VALUE='Azzera'><INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='Invia'>
</FORM>";
if(isset($_COOKIE['nome'])&&isset($_COOKIE['cognome']))
{
    $nome =(string) $COOKIE['nome'];
    $cognome =(string) $COOKIE['cognome'];

}else{
    $nome = "";
    $cognome = "";
}
setcookie('nome','cognome', $nome, $cognome, time()+3600);
if($nome == "" && $cognome == ""){
    echo "Benvenuto inserici i valori nel form";
}else{
    echo "ciao $nome, $cognome";
}

?>
```

Comment: The  submitted data will be in $_POST, not $_COOKIE. Firstly, go and take a php and html forms tutorial so you understand how the basics of that works, and then go and read about what cookies are and how you set them. You seem to have got confused somehow between the two separate concepts of forms and cookies...it's not clear how you came to the conclusion that $_COOKIE should be used in this situation - you won't see it in any examples of simple forms like this.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are confused between POST and COOKIE. COOKIE is not used for submitting data in forms.
here is a quick example on how it could be done:

```
     <?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name=$_POST['name'];
echo $name
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```